# Font-size changes input type range size

Tags: html, css, firefox

It only happens in Firefox:

```css
input {
  font-size: 72px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Since the element has no actual text inside, it seems like a bug to me. What do you think?

Comment: I cant understand your problem. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

So based on what I understand from your question, it looks like the padding around the input is being shrunken.

Try this:

```
input:active {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Mess around with the padding and see if it effects the size when active.